# The regular expression doesn't work equal in different code even being the same input

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a code, a part of this code uses a regular expression which is:

```js
var ex = "122", checker = /(\d)\1{1,}/g,
    c = pattern.test(+ex);
if(c) console.log(`works.`);
```

My goal is to check if there is a repeated number.

The problem arises when I use the above snippet in a larger section of code. I have the **same input** at the above snippet, but in the below code, the regex isnt work

Here is the code:

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    var clone = [].concat(sequence),
        l = clone.length,
        pattern = /(\d)\1{2,}/ig;
    if (pattern.test(clone)) {
        return false;
    }

    var sorted = sequence.splice(0).sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        }),
        element, finder, checker = /(\d)\1{1,}/g;
        
    for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        element = clone[i];
        finder = sorted.indexOf(element);
        clone.splice(i, 1);
        sorted.splice(finder, 1);
        if (clone.join("") === sorted.join("") && !checker.test(+clone.join(""))) {
            /*
            In the conditional above, i use the regex
            */
            console.log(`
            Same input: ${+clone.join("")}
            
            PD: This message, it should not be shown, since the conditional should not have been true,
            `);
            return true;
        } else {
            clone.splice(i, 0, element);
            sorted.splice(finder, 0, element);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 1, 2]))
```

So in the first snippet code, the regex return true, but in the second snippet code, or the regex is bad or the negation isn't works, because i'm negating the result of regex, because the regex in the second snippet code have the same input as the first, so the negation of true is false .

Comment: Your first code block is supposed to be an example of how it works. If so, then you need to use the **exact same code** in your second code block. You go from `pattern = /(\d)\1{1,}/g` to `pattern = /(\d)\1{2,}/ig`. Which is it that you're expecting?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test says `test() called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.` So the first time it is returning false, however in your console.log it returns true.

Comment: I have expressed my problem badly, I have corrected my publication

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `/g` in your Regexp - when this is used, and the regex is executed multiple times, it will always begin where it left off last time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex

> This property is set only if the regular expression instance used the "g" flag to indicate a global search. The following rules apply:
>
> If lastIndex is greater than the length of the string, test() and exec() fail, then lastIndex is set to 0.
>
> If lastIndex is equal to the length of the string and if the regular expression matches the empty string, then the regular expression matches input starting at lastIndex.
>
> If lastIndex is equal to the length of the string and if the regular expression does not match the empty string, then the regular expression mismatches input, and lastIndex is reset to 0.
>
> Otherwise, lastIndex is set to the next position following the most recent match.

You can see this is happening by logging `checker.lastIndex` before you do `checker.test`, and you will see that when it fails, `lastIndex` is not 0.

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
    var clone = [].concat(sequence),
        l = clone.length,
        pattern = /(\d)\1{2,}/ig;
    if (pattern.test(clone)) {
        return false;
    }

    var sorted = sequence.splice(0).sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        }),
        element, finder, checker = /(\d)\1{1,}/g;
        
    for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        element = clone[i];
        finder = sorted.indexOf(element);
        clone.splice(i, 1);
        sorted.splice(finder, 1);
        console.log(checker.lastIndex)
        if (clone.join("") === sorted.join("") && !checker.test(+clone.join(""))) {
            /*
            checker.test(+clone.join("")) <-- HERE IS THE REGEX
            */
            console.log( `The number is ${+clone.join("")} 
  and the regex return: ${checker.test(+clone.join(""))}, 
  so, if the regex return true, the negation operator, isnt work ? because im negating the returned value from the regex !checker.test
  `); // FALSE ? Why... ??
            return true;
        } else {
            clone.splice(i, 0, element);
            sorted.splice(finder, 0, element);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 1, 2]))
```

Or, to use your first "working" code:

```js
var ex = "122", checker = /(\d)\1{1,}/g,
    c = checker.test(+ex);
if(c) console.log(`works.`);
c = checker.test(+ex);
if(c) console.log(`works.`);
```

And it will only print `works` once, because you are checking it *more than once* and it has a `/g` on the Regexp.

Comment: I have expressed my problem badly, I have corrected my publication, please see now dave

Comment: My answer still applies.  You are checking a regex more than once, and the regex has a global flag.  So you are getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sort list and return only incremental values without using regex:

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence (array) {
  return Array.from(array)
    .sort()
    .reduce(function(acc, cur, i, arr) {
      if (arr[i - 1] !== cur) {
        return acc.concat(cur)
      } else {
        return acc
      }
    }, [])
}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 1, 2])) // [1,2]
console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 2, 4, 3])) // [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code should work like this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3A9HkAbky3M

Comment: I've edited the example to run more similarly to what I think you are trying to accomplish, again with no Regex

Comment: i see many times your parameters name, is a convention? the "acc", "cur" and "arr" ? and and if so, what variables is that convention for? accumulators , flags ? or what

Comment: acc = accumulator, in this case an array
cur = current (the current value)
arr = the target array of the reducer